# How to get tags with custom taxonomy field?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

I have added custom taxonomy fields on tags but when I use `get_tags()` it does not return custom field. Right now I am using `get_term_meta()` for custom field but I have 4000 records of tags so when I fire the query to get tags it fires 4000 queries so any way to minimize it or get results in 1 query with `get_tags()`.

Comment: No, I’m afraid. get_tags gets only tags, not its meta...

Answer (score -1):

Have you try 
      `$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);` ?

```
<?php foreach($tags as $tag): ?>
    <span class="tag-element">
        <?=$tag->name ?>,
    </span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I want all tags not single tag

Comment: what about loop foreach on all elements?

Comment: I edit my answer , look now

Comment: But I have 4000 records so its fire 4000 queries so its not efficient. I want it with one query.